# How to know if I am warmed up?

Tags: exercise, bodybuilding

I am new on bodybuilding and I know I should warmup before lifting. So how do I know whether I have warmed up enough.

Comment: Your joints feel looser (no cracking) and stretching is less painful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your heart rate will be elevated by about 20bpm or more.

You will feel warmer.

You will have mobilised your joints and feel limber.

With weightlifting, warm up sets are usually sufficient after some mobility: 8-10x Reps at 50%, 70% and 90% of your training weight. Don't neglect to warm-up if you are attempting a 1RM, people often do.

Comment: Only comment I have to this answer is that once you get closer to your working weight, you can reduce your warm-up reps in order to keep some energy for your working set and use that warm-up set to gauge how you feel for your work set.

Comment: And if you have just done your sets of cable lat pulldown you don't need to do another 3 warmup sets on the cable row.